# Minimal installation of OpenSolaris (or alternative)?

Tags: installation, opensolaris

I want to create a storage server - I've chosen to use OpenSolaris to take advantage of ZFS.

I'm looking for a way to install OpenSolaris without any graphical components, just a command line interface, but I don't really know where to start.

---

Edit: Perhaps I'm making things too complicated - instead of removing the GUI packages, is it easy to just configure OpenSolaris to boot to a CLI instead of loading Gnome on startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI isn't mandatory. You can disable it with "svcadm disable gdm" after installation. As already stated, there is also a text only installer should your hardware is missing a graphic card or should you do not want to use it.
There are also small footprint distributions based on the OpenSolaris kernel like JeOS and Milax:
http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Project+jeos/WebHome
http://www.milax.org/

Answer (score 1):

There is a text-only version on genunix :
http://genunix.org/
It's textinstall-134-x86.iso

Answer (score 0):

At my work we once created a minimal jumpstart install for Solaris 9 (long time ago...).
We needed at least the cluster package SUNWCreq
But then you can still remove packages.
We finally ended up with a working system 
with about 70 Packages.
But even then you can strip i.e. sudo, tcsh and probably some more.
Just use pkgrm and see if you went too far... :)
The packages we ended up with:

> application SMCsudo        sudo
>   system      SUNWaccu       System Accounting, (Usr)
>   system      SUNWadmc       System administration core libraries
>   system      SUNWadmfw      System & Network Administration Framework
>   system      SUNWadmr       System & Network Administration Root
>   system      SUNWatfsr      AutoFS, (Root)
>   system      SUNWatfsu      AutoFS, (Usr)
>   system      SUNWbash       GNU Bourne-Again shell (bash)
>   system      SUNWbip        Basic IP commands (Usr)
>   system      SUNWbzip       The bzip compression utility
>   system      SUNWcar        Core Architecture, (Root)
>   system      SUNWcarx       Core Architecture, (Root) (64-bit)
>   system      SUNWced        Sun GigaSwift Ethernet Adapter (32-bit Driver)
>   system      SUNWcedx       Sun GigaSwift Ethernet Adapter (64-bit Driver)
>   system      SUNWcsd        Core Solaris Devices
>   system      SUNWcsl        Core Solaris, (Shared Libs)
>   system      SUNWcslx       Core Solaris Libraries (64-bit)
>   system      SUNWcsr        Core Solaris, (Root)
>   system      SUNWcsu        Core Solaris, (Usr)
>   system      SUNWcsxu       Core Solaris (Usr) (64-bit)
>   system      SUNWeridx      Sun RIO 10/100 Mb Ethernet Drivers (64-bit)
>   system      SUNWesu        Extended System Utilities
>   system      SUNWesxu       Extended System Utilities (64-bit)
>   system      SUNWfns        Federated Naming System
>   system      SUNWfnsx       Federated Naming System (64-bit)
>   system      SUNWgzip       The GNU Zip (gzip) compression utility
>   system      SUNWhmd        SunSwift Adapter Drivers
>   system      SUNWhmdx       SunSwift Adapter Drivers (64-bit)
>   system      SUNWi15cs      X11 ISO8859-15 Codeset Support
>   system      SUNWi1cs       X11 ISO8859-1 Codeset Support
>   system      SUNWkvm        Core Architecture, (Kvm)
>   system      SUNWkvmx       Core Architecture (Kvm) (64-bit)
>   system      SUNWlibC       Sun Workshop Compilers Bundled libC
>   system      SUNWlibCx      Sun WorkShop Bundled 64-bit libC
>   system      SUNWlibms      Forte Developer Bundled shared libm
>   system      SUNWlldap      LDAP Libraries
>   system      SUNWlmsx       Forte Developer Bundled 64-bit shared libm
>   system      SUNWloc        System Localization
>   system      SUNWlocx       System Localization (64-bit)
>   system      SUNWnamos      Northern America OS Support
>   system      SUNWnamox      Northern America 64-bit OS Support
>   system      SUNWnfscr      Network File System (NFS) client support (Root)
>   system      SUNWnfscu      Network File System (NFS) client support (Usr)
>   system      SUNWnfscx      Network File System (NFS) client support (Root) (64-bit)
>   system      SUNWnfssr      Network File System (NFS) server support (Root)
>   system      SUNWnfssu      Network File System (NFS) server support (Usr)
>   system      SUNWnfssx      Network File System (NFS) server support (Root) (64-bit)
>   system      SUNWntpr       NTP, (Root)
>   system      SUNWntpu       NTP, (Usr)
>   system      SUNWpd         PCI Drivers
>   system      SUNWpdx        PCI Drivers (64-bit)
>   system      SUNWpiclr      PICL Framework (Root)
>   system      SUNWpiclu      PICL Libraries, and Plugin Modules (Usr)
>   system      SUNWpiclx      PICL Libraries (64-bit)
>   system      SUNWpl5u       Perl 5.6.1 (core)
>   system      SUNWpl5v       Perl 5.6.1 (non-core)
>   system      SUNWrcmdc      Remote Network Client Commands
>   system      SUNWses        SCSI Enclosure Services Device Driver
>   system      SUNWsesx       SCSI Enclosure Services Device Driver (64-bit)
>   system      SUNWsndmr      Sendmail root
>   system      SUNWsndmu      Sendmail user
>   system      SUNWsolnm      Solaris Naming Enabler
>   system      SUNWsprot      Solaris Bundled tools
>   system      SUNWswmt       Install and Patch Utilities
>   system      SUNWtcsh       Tenex C-shell (tcsh) (not really necessary...)
>   system      SUNWtnetc      Telnet Command (client)
>   system      SUNWtoo        Programming Tools
>   system      SUNWtoox       Programming Tools (64-bit)
>   system      SUNWzlib       The Zip compression library
>   system      SUNWzlibx      The Zip compression library (64-bit)

Comment: So could I just start will a vanilla install from the live CD then remove the X11 & Gnome packages to get a system that just boots to a CLI?

Answer (score 0):

We use OpenSolaris 2009.06 and the b132 preview on an 8GB USB stick. We don't worry about the extra GUI parts.

But you could try [Nexenta Community Edition](http://nexenta.org/) or [EON NAS](http://eonstorage.blogspot.com/) (Embedded ON, Network Attached Storage)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I guess an OpenSolaris install without a GUI is near to impossible? ;-)
Been a while I installed Solaris and never used a gui, things *are* changing for the worse...
But then my best bet would be to do an install and make sure you have sshd runnning. Then start removing packages (pkginfo and pkgrm are your friends) just *till* you still have a working server and maybe the above list, though dated, helps a little...

Gee, if you insist on zfs (for probably good reasons) then FreeBSD can help?
Otherwise, skip zfs, there are many good storage servers without it running Linux :)

Good luck!

Comment: ZFS on FreeBSD is a bit outdated, in case he wants dedupe etc.

Comment: Yep, therefore the question mark :)

Comment: Well, may be it is not as outdated as it seemed: http://itmanagement.earthweb.com/osrc/article.php/3926181/FreeBSD-82-Expands-ZFS-Support----Without-Oracle.htm